# "The type does not fulfill the required lifetime" for flatbuffers table in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

I have some flatbuffers IDL:

```
table Filter {
  text: string (required);
}
```

which generates the following .rs:

```
...
pub struct Filter<'a> {
  pub _tab: flatbuffers::Table<'a>,
}
...
```

I'm trying to add some trait impl for it:

```
pub trait TFilter {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Any;
}
...
impl TFilter for crate::schema_generated::Filter<'_> {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any { self }
    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Any { self }
}
```

I'm getting the following:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements

note: ...so that the type `schema_generated::Filter<'_>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
```

If i add lifetimes:

```
// flatbuffers-based impl
impl<'a> TFilter for crate::schema_generated::Filter<'a> {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &'a dyn Any { self }
    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &'a mut dyn Any { self }
}
```

i'm getting the following:

```
the type `schema_generated::Filter<'a>` does not fulfill the required lifetime

note: type must satisfy the static lifetimerustc(E0477)
```

I'm not sure i understand that is meant.
If i understand correctly i need to mark `as_any` living no longer than `crate::schema_generated::Filter`, is it correct?

Any clue? Where did `'static` requirement come from?

PS. I've found the [following](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/4924), but i'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator yes, but can you provide a small example for my case? BTW that answer is not accepted..

Comment: There's no example to make. The answer there is correct that you can't use `Any` for types with lifetimes, `Any` requires `'static`. You *could* `impl TFilter for Filter<'static>`, but that's probably not helpful.

Comment: As the answer to the other question also says, *without further context, it is difficult to say.* It seems you are trying to use `Any` to solve some problem you encountered with `Filter`, but if `Filter` contains lifetimes, `Any` simply is not the solution. Perhaps there are other ways you could achieve the same thing without using `Any`?